# Calling a single div from another page

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Is it possible that calling a single div (without master page) by the
use of `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe style=" width: 1150px; height: 600px;" id="frame" src="EmployeeAllowance.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
```

Above code is working but it show the full page including the
master page. How can I call the content wrapper div as a single part?

Comment: The `src` of an iframe can only request an entire page. If you only want a single div, you need to put that it its own page, and request it.

Comment: will u give a example.. i don't know how it done in my project @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you also use `jQuery` tag, here's an answer using the `jQuery .load` in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zty8abpa/)

using this markup

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

and script

```
$("#box").load("/ #run");
```

it will load the root url from http://jsfiddle.net because you're using `/`, then it will load the selector from that page, which in this case is a `Hyperlink` with id `run`, you can use the demo and try changing the selector to `#savenew`, `#actions`, `.actionItem`, and any other selector to test it.

For more information, you can take a look at the [jQuery .load api](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: there is a problem.....

Comment: All textbox have a comma while refreshing the page

Comment: $("#new-projects").load("LeavePolicy.aspx #leavepolicy");

Comment: this scrip making the comma

Comment: while removing the script it's perfect